# Multiply a list of tuples by a constant

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples as follows:

`[ (-100,-100), (-100,0), (-50,-100), (-50,-50), (-50,0), (-50,50), (-50,100), (0,-100), (0,-50), (0,0), (0,50), (0,100), (50,-100), (50,50), (50,0), (50,50), (50,100), (100,100), (100,0)]`

How can I multiply each element of each tuple by a constant C, in a Pythonic way, retaining the original order and structure of the list of tuples?

In other words, I should end up with:

`[ (-C*100, -C*100), (-C*100, 0), ... , (C*100, C*100), (C*100, 0) ]`

Comment: `newlist = [(item[0] * C, item[1] * C) for item in oldlist]`

Comment: Ermahgerd... Five solutions and *nobody* unpacked like `[(C * x, C * y) for x, y in lst]` ... what is going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension should do nicely. If we don't know if all of the tuples are the same length, we can iterate over them with a generator expression, and then convert that to a tuple.

```
data = [ (-100,-100), (-100,0), (-50,-100), (-50,-50), (-50,0), (-50,50), (-50,100), (0,-100), (0,-50), (0,0), (0,50), (0,100), (50,-100), (50,50), (50,0), (50,50), (50,100), (100,100), (100,0)]

multiplied = [tuple(x * constant for x in tpl) for tpl in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what list comprehension is for! Try this:

```py
[ (C*i[0], C*i[1]) for i in originalList]
```

Here, you just iterate over list x, returning a tuple for each element with the individual parts multiplied by C.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in a Pythonic way would likely be using list comprehension:

```py
out = [(C * t[0], C * t[1]) for t in lst]
```

This takes each tuple in the list, and multiples both parts of the tuple by `C`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick list comprehension will do;

```
#tuples = your tuple list
[(C*t[0], C*t[1]) for t in tuples]
```